# Can't access "publish_stream" permission, iOs app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, ipad

I have an iOS app, which should upload video on Facebook. But I can't set permission "publish_stream" for uploading video. What should I do?

Comment: what means "you can´t"?

Comment: btw, publish_stream is deprecated, use publish_actions instead

Comment: I was trying to add permissions programmatically, but it didn't work. Facebook's had only standard permissions

Comment: "it didn´t work" is still not enough information. please be as detailed as possible and include the relevant code too.